# In PHP querying quotes proper from MySql

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySql I have data stored like this

```
....they try to provide time off to employees for volunteering, since they've experienced   such a huge growth period and "never got out of start-up mode," ....
```

but once I query it and echo to in PHP it comes out to

```
they try to provide time off to employees for volunteering, since they�ve experienced such a huge growth period and �never got out of start-up mode,�
```

Do have to replace all the double and single quotes in my data within the database with `&#34;` ?

Comment: It might not be a single quote. There are some other characters similar to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change row collation to UTF-8.